# Is there a Regex function for starting at a certain set of characters and ending once it finds a specific character, capturing line breaks in between?

Tags: regex, discord

I'm sifting through some Discord messages to make an AI, and in order to do this I need to get the text down to:

```
Name
Message
```

There's plenty of things to account for, like the attached date, full username, and all kinds of other things the program supports (reactions, pins, etc.). However, I'm coming across a problem with YouTube descriptions that embed. Specifically, if a YouTube description has a line break in it, than the current regex I have written to deal with it doesn't work. Here's the example I'm currently dealing with.

```
[11/15/2019 9:23 PM] (name censored)#5152
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pISHt9TzwAA

{Embed}
Ethan Siegel
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pISHt9TzwAA
Strobe Illusion: How to Hallucinate without drugs
This is a strobing animation designed to induce hallucinations.

This should NOT BE TRIED BY PEOPLE WITH EPILEPSY, or people prone to visually induced seizures.

Stare at the center for 30 seconds, then look away and observe how objects appear to have their size distorted.

F...


[11/15/2019 9:37 PM] (name censored)#3390
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-ztVMxfDTQ

{Embed}
maio290
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-ztVMxfDTQ
Hallucinate without Drugs.
View in Fullscreen!

From the Program Virtual Hypnotist: http://www.majorgeeks.com/Virtual_Hypnotist_d4623.html


[11/15/2019 10:09 PM] (name censored)#3390
```

If I apply `/{Embed}(\n.+)+/` to this, then everything before the first line break in the descriptions will be captured, but everything after won't. How could I fix this?

I tried to capture embedded YouTube descriptions using regex, and I expected all of it to be captured, but line breaks cause problems with the capturing. I tried to capture it with /.+/ and /\X/, but neither worked as expected.

Comment: Use the `s` flag to the regexp to make `.` match newlines. Then `.+` will match across multiple lines.

Comment: @Barmar this has the same problem as \X, it just selects the entire document.

Comment: You need to specify pattern for the end of the match. `startPattern.+endPattern` And use `.+?` for a non-greedy version that doesn't match multiple occurrences.

Comment: `/\{Embed}.+?(?=(\{Embed}|$))/s`

Comment: I wasn't able to get yours working even with with s tag, and I'm still struggling with this a bit. I'd like the embed to end at the next opening bracket, the next "[".

Comment: What language are you using, BTW?

Comment: Works here: https://regex101.com/r/2xAi26/1

Comment: I'm just using https://regex101.com, haha. I probably could do this in Python to all the text files at once, but this is easier and more straightforward for me.

Comment: If you want to end at `[`, then use `(?=(\[|$))` instead.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2xAi26/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\{Embed}[^\[]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/REvBNP/1).

*Details*:

- `\{Embed}` - an `{Embed}` string (the `{` escaping depends on the regex flavor)
- `[^\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` (the `[` inside the character class might need no escaping, it depends on the regex flavor).